# check count of all groups in case statements

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a situation in which i need to group the applicant based on some column value 
**(shown below)** and find the count of that group.
Currently the query is returning only those columns which has a count of more than 0.

What modification should be done to the query so that it shows all groups and its counts as zero?

Query:

```
select Applicant_info.range as [Income Range], count(*) as [Total Students],order_number =
          CASE range
             WHEN 'Did not specify' THEN '1'
             WHEN '0-25000' THEN '2'
             WHEN '25001-50000' THEN '3'
             WHEN '50001-75000' THEN '4'
             WHEN '75001-100000' THEN '5'
             WHEN '100001-200000' THEN '6'
             WHEN '200000 and Above' THEN '7'
          END
    from (
      select case  
        when Annual_Income is null or Annual_Income = '' then 'Did not specify' 
        when Annual_Income between 0 and 25000 then '0-25000'
        when Annual_Income between 25001 and 50000 then '25001-50000'
        when Annual_Income between 50001 and 75000 then '50001-75000'
        when Annual_Income between 75001 and 100000 then '75001-100000'
        when Annual_Income between 100001 and 200000 then '100001-200000'
        when Annual_Income > 200000 then '200000 and Above'
        end as range
      from Applicant_info)Applicant_info
    group by Applicant_info.range
    order by order_number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a separate `CASE` expression for each one like this:

```
Select 
  range as [Income Range], 
  SUM(CASE when Annual_Income is null or Annual_Income = '' then END) AS 'Did not specify',
  SUM(CASE when Annual_Income between 0 and 25000 then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '0-25000',
  SUM(CASE when Annual_Income between 25001 and 50000 then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '25001-50000',
  SUM(CASE when Annual_Income between 50001 and 75000 then 1 ELSE 0END) AS  '50001-75000',
  SUM(CASE when Annual_Income between 75001 and 100000 then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  '75001-100000',
  SUM(CASE when Annual_Income between 100001 and 200000 then 1 ELSE 0END) AS  '100001-200000',
  SUM(CASE when Annual_Income > 200000 then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  '200000 and Above'
from Applicant_info
GROUP BY range;
```

**Note that:** This `SUM` function is actually a count, because it sums either 0 or 1.

Comment: @Shah - Do you got any errors, if so, edit your question and add them there or with a comment here.

Comment: Yes the range is causing the issue, after commenting it out it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use an outer join and a lookup table to ensure that all ranges are included even if the count is zero.

```
SELECT C.[Range], COUNT(B.[Income_Band]) AS [Count]
FROM Applicant_info
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN Annual_Income IS NULL OR ISNUMERIC(Annual_Income) = 0 THEN 1
            WHEN Annual_Income > 200000 THEN 7
            WHEN Annual_Income > 100000 THEN 6
            WHEN Annual_Income > 75000  THEN 5
            WHEN Annual_Income > 50000  THEN 4
            WHEN Annual_Income > 25000  THEN 3
            WHEN Annual_Income >= 0  THEN 2
            ELSE 1
        END AS [Income_Band]
) B
RIGHT JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 AS [Income_Band], 'Did not specify' AS [Range]
    UNION SELECT 2, '0-25000'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, '25001-50000'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, '50001-75000'
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, '75001-100000'
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, '100001-200000'
    UNION ALL SELECT 7, '200000 and Above'
) C
    ON C.[Income_Band] = B.[Income_Band]
GROUP BY C.[Range], C.[Income_Band]
ORDER BY C.[Income_Band]
```